# How to get birthday info using google integration in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am able to access Google user's email, display name, and profile picture but while accessing the about me and birthday I get nil.

Is there any special permission required?

I am using below code on IBAction

```
- (IBAction)loginUsingGoogle:(id)sender {
  [GPPSignInButton class];
  GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
  signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
  signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
  signIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
  signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];
  signIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusMe];
  signIn.delegate = self;
  NSLog(@"Google Button clicked");
  [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
}
```

I am using above code to hit the google api but unable to extract birthday and about me info, I am using below way to extarct user detail but birthday gives a nil value.

```
GTLPlusPerson *per = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].googlePlusUser;
GTMOAuth2Authentication *authentication = [GPPSignIn    sharedInstance].authentication;
self.nameTexField.text = per.name.givenName;
self.birthDayTextField.text = per.birthday;//
self.emailIdTextField.text = authentication.userEmail;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to specify the scope of google api to get the birthday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896424/how-to-specify-the-scope-of-google-api-to-get-the-birthday)

Comment: Is it suitable for ios Development.

Comment: Answer is the same it depends upon if the user in question has set it public

Comment: It means that this is a matter of user's permission. ok thanx alot BTW  is above code fine for the case of  birthday.?

Comment: By which permission i will get birthday please suggest me ...