# Not able to retrieve gender in google plus ios sdk

Tags: swift, google-plus

I used  `GTLQueryPlus.queryForPeopleGetWithUserId("me")` for retrieving logged in user information. I am not getting the gender in json. When I set the gender visibility to 'public' instead of 'my circles' from my google plus profile, then I got the gender.

How to get the gender info without changing the settings from googe plus profile settings?

scopes used: `signIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusMe, kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoProfile, kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to specify the scope of google api to get the birthday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896424/how-to-specify-the-scope-of-google-api-to-get-the-birthday)

Comment: That question refers to birthday but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access what a user has set to public.  If the user doesn't want this information public then you cant have the information.

Just because I authenticate your application doesn't mean that I want you to for example to see my address or in this case my gender.   So I don't set them public you cant see them.