# What the heck with Google+ API on Android?

Tags: android, google-plus

I try to get my birthday date using deprecated `Plus.API`. I request scopes: `Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE`, `Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN` and `Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read")`.

I even got dialog from Google Plus, that app request full birtday date. But wth I got response with null birthady even if it is pblic on mu G+ page?

Code:

```
public static final Scope SCOPE_PLUS_BIRTHDAY = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read");

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestId()
            .requestProfile()
            .requestScopes(SCOPE_PLUS_BIRTHDAY, Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE, Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
            .enableAutoManage(mActivity, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
```

Response:

```
[{value='antoxa2584@gmail.com', key='email', parentId=null}, {value='Антон Артемов', key='name', parentId=null}, {value='https://plus.google.com/100328752299073028996', key='url', parentId=null}, {value='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WNQOIPjFjtY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAP7E/LjtF7njMedE/photo.jpg?sz=50', key='photo_url', parentId=null}, {value='0', key='age_range_max', parentId=null}, {value='21', key='age_range_min', parentId=null}, {value='null', key='about_me', parentId=null}, {value='null', key='birthday', parentId=null}, {value='null', key='location', parentId=null}, {value='male', key='gender', parentId=null}, {value='ru', key='language', parentId=null}, {value='null', key='nick_name', parentId=null}, {value='0', key='relat_status', parentId=null}]
```

Comment: is that even a valid scope where did you find that?

Comment: @DaImTo, yes  Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE, Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN default in Plus. SCOPE_PLUS_BIRTHDAY I found on some git

Comment: I have never seen it before and I have googled it I cant find any refrence for it https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth  unless you can find some way to prove it exists and its not something you are just trying to send this is probably a duplicate of another question.   Happy to remove it if someone can show its an android only issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to specify the scope of google api to get the birthday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896424/how-to-specify-the-scope-of-google-api-to-get-the-birthday)

Comment: @DaImTo, nope, that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the birthday without setting it to public. I don't believe the user's birth year is returned either. You can use the age range for verifying a user's age and can use their birthday (if they make it public) for social engagement on their birthday.

Try [using the API Explorer to test this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=me&fields=ageRange%252Cbirthday&_h=3&) after setting your profile to public.