# Get gender for gmail when signup

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I want to get the gender of users when they signup using there gmail account

I'm using this code get get a token that contain user information

```
const scriptGSI = new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
            script.addEventListener('load', () => {
                resolve();
            });
            script.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
                reject(e);
            });
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }));
```

I get a token contain those informations:

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com", 
  "nbf":  161803398874,
  "aud": "314159265-pi.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
  "sub": "3141592653589793238", 
  "hd": "gmail.com", 
  "email": "elisa.g.beckett@gmail.com", 
  "email_verified": true, 
  "azp": "314159265-pi.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "name": "Elisa Beckett",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/e2718281828459045235360uler",
  "given_name": "Elisa",
  "family_name": "Beckett",
  "iat": 1596474000, 
  "exp": 1596477600, 
  "jti": "abc161803398874def"
}
```

I want to get the user gender, what can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

oooh this is complicated. (I just set up somthing using google signin i feel your pain)

Ok, so go to your google console, and enter the project that this signin is controled by. Then, using a restricted scope, under People Api;
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes
scroll down to People API and there is a gender.read scope. Enable that, and try your program again.

Comment: to use Peaple Api do I need an acess token ?

Comment: it is possible to get the gender using https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client

Comment: Yes that is what you use to get the data, but you have to enable the scope on your google console project first.