# Google OAuth scope option is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

When I set the OAuth scope to retrieve data such as `date of birth` or `gender`, the pop up window notifies the user that there is additional requested data but when the `onSuccess` method is triggered, the requested data is not available on the payload.

```
function onSuccess(googleUser) {
  console.log('Logged in as: ' + JSON.stringify(googleUser));
}
function onFailure(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
function renderButton() {
  gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
    'scope': 'profile email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
    'width': 240,
    "fetch_basic_profile": false,
    'height': 50,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'dark',
    'onsuccess': onSuccess,
    'onfailure': onFailure
  });
}
```

In the Google Cloud credentials console I have added all these scopes to the non-sensitive scope section and I am testing the app against my own account so I have already made sure that the gender or the date of birth (missing in the provided code) are already available.

In other words no matter what additional scope I provide, the `googleUser` object always returns the same type of data.

Comment: is the users birthday public https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896958/1841839

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo: I figured it out. Google has terrible documentation on the OAuth service although they have a nice documentation for Place API! This is an expected behavior, actually the additional info must be retrieved via the API mentioned here `https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get` after the sign in.